# Send and Receive Messages between Android App and Winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, azure, google-cloud-messaging

Looked for a long time and didn't find anything that showed this, so I apologize in advance I missed something.

I have an android app running on KitKat (Android 4.4.2) and a Winforms application running Windows 7. I need to send messages between the two of them.

Clearly GCM works to get the message to the Android device. I have code that sends from Winforms to the Android Device using GCM. I cannot find a way to have the Android App send anything *BACK* though. Is it possible to have a Winforms app *RECEIVE* a GCM Message? Do I have to use Azure? (All examples there seem to focus on the Windows App store and Windows 8.1 neither one of which can be a solution in this case due to client restraints.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting this here in case anyone stumbles across it and has a similar question. This is not really an answer. Still hoping someone comes on here and shows that I am wrong. But after 26 days, no one has even offered a suggestion, so I'm guessing not.

There is no way that I have seen that allows for this the way I had hoped. Windows 7 doesn't have this built in to it (AFAIK). Windows 10 should have it built in, but Windows 7 pre-dates the huge shift to the cloud, and didn't have it in the design. If I were working with something like Xamarin -- which is a cross-platform tool, this might be possible. But there is no concept in Windows 7 for receiving messages from the Cloud.

In order to accomplish this, there would have to be some sort of server added to the mix that could take messages and pass them along via a REST API. This is beyond the scope of what I wanted to code.

The solution I found, and that works for me, is to use Microsofts API that wraps a REST service. This allows for communication to OneDrive, for example. That is what I am using as my intermediary REST server.

[Microsoft LIVE SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243641.aspx#consent)

This has a pretty good sample list of Android examples, and can be used for what I need. The good thing is the Upstream is just a simple call, and I don't need to have the Android device poll anything (which kills the battery). The laptop will need to poll OneDrive, but its plugged in so there is no battery life concern.

One thing to be aware of, though, is that Microsoft sort of hints that they don't want a bunch of traffic headed to OneDrive. This is from the overview doc:

> **Throttling**
>
> OneDrive has limits in place to make sure that individuals and apps do
>   not adversely affect the experience of other users. When an activity
>   exceeds OneDrive's limits, API requests will be rejected for a period
>   of time. OneDrive may also return a Retry-After header with the number
>   of seconds your app should wait before sending more requests.

Although, I have never seen what those limits actually are, so YMMV.